# iCal won't accept my ics file

Tags: icalendar

My web app generates ics files. These can be read successfully by Google Calender, but not iCal, which shows the error "iCal can’t read this calendar file. No events have been added to your iCal calendar.".

Why doesn't my ics file load in iCal?

Here is the file contents:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:1.0
PRODID:-//Third Workplace//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Meeting at Third Workplace in Office #4
DTSTART;TZID=UTC;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20120820T160000Z
DTEND;TZID=UTC;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20120820T170000Z
DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20120820T084134
UID:65---eede0aac722e48979bd2237814da9e3d@thirdworkplace.com
LOCATION:Office #4 at Third Workplace Contra Costa Centre
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:ram@rachum.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Here is the [original, binary version](http://i.minus.com/1345987205/t7CGBeRX1Y3cfbto367nOA/dbIG0v5sP00Nj/reservation.ics).

Comment: You might want to censor some of the details in that ICS file, like email addresses.

Comment: I have. I've replaced the email with my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change that version to 2.0, and watch the magic happen :-)

TG

Comment: is it still version 2.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a lot of difficulties with this:

It was frustrating  because a downloaded file would open in Google Calendar or iCal, but it would not load as feed in either.  I would get these errors in Google Calendar when I did add by URL: "Failed to import calendar from" (sitename) or "Could not fetch the URL."

Here's what I had to do:

Have duration or endtime for events, NOT BOTH.

I also had to remove this from the header:
content-disposition: attachment; filename=Schedule.ics;

Also, to check if it's valid, Google a validator or try http://icalvalid.cloudapp.net/.